# least astonishment transgressed by `nl` on Darwin

Tags: darwin, nl

Transgression of [least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment):

```
bash-5.0$ (for i in {1..1000010}; do echo $i; done) | nl | tail -24
999987  999987
999988  999988
999989  999989
999990  999990
999991  999991
999992  999992
999993  999993
999994  999994
999995  999995
999996  999996
999997  999997
999998  999998
999999  999999
000000  1000000
000001  1000001
000002  1000002
000003  1000003
000004  1000004
000005  1000005
000006  1000006
000007  1000007
000008  1000008
000009  1000009
000010  1000010
bash-5.0$ uname -a
Darwin llc.local 19.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 20
20; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64        
bash-5.0$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.4
[...]
bash-5.0$ _
```

Compare with expectation:

```
admin@ip-w-x-y-z:~$ (for i in {1..1000010}; do echo $i; done) | nl | tail -24
999987  999987
999988  999988
999989  999989
999990  999990
999991  999991
999992  999992
999993  999993
999994  999994
999995  999995
999996  999996
999997  999997
999998  999998
999999  999999
1000000 1000000
1000001 1000001
1000002 1000002
1000003 1000003
1000004 1000004
1000005 1000005
1000006 1000006
1000007 1000007
1000008 1000008
1000009 1000009
1000010 1000010
admin@ip-w-x-y-z:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-w-x-y-z 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u4 (2019-07-19)
 x86_64 GNU/Linux
admin@ip-w-x-y-z:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)
Release:    9.9
Codename:   stretch
admin@ip-w-x-y-z:~$ _
```

I'm curious what are your thoughts about this and how to overcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default *width* of the numbers added by `nl` is 6.  This is documented in the `nl` manual as well as [specified by the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html).

macOS `nl` truncates the numbers if they are longer than the width (and the manual documents this), while GNU `nl` does not (but does not document this). Neither behavior seems to be disallowed by the standard text.

To number lines that require more than 6 digits, specify a larger width using the `-w` option of `nl`:

```
$ (for i in {1..1000010}; do echo $i; done) | nl -w 7 | tail -24
 999987 999987
 999988 999988
 999989 999989
 999990 999990
 999991 999991
 999992 999992
 999993 999993
 999994 999994
 999995 999995
 999996 999996
 999997 999997
 999998 999998
 999999 999999
1000000 1000000
1000001 1000001
1000002 1000002
1000003 1000003
1000004 1000004
1000005 1000005
1000006 1000006
1000007 1000007
1000008 1000008
1000009 1000009
1000010 1000010
```

Comment: I know `for` and brace expansion are questionable. Thanks for staying on topic.

Comment: @41754 Yeah, that bit could have been done differently, but it wasn't really the main issue in the question. Be well!

Comment: POSIX does say the default should use `%6d` format, so macOS would appear not to be compliant here.